# OSX yosimite curl issue with php apache

Tags: php, macos, apache, curl, php-5.6

I am having issues with my apache being able to curl from my website. I get the
following error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in /path/to/file on line 16
```

I thought I had installed curl but apparently not. May be not for webserver part of it because when I do `php -i` in **cli** mode I get the following

```
curl

cURL support => enabled
cURL Information => 7.37.1
Age => 3
Features
AsynchDNS => Yes
CharConv => No
Debug => No
GSS-Negotiate => Yes
IDN => No
IPv6 => Yes
krb4 => No
Largefile => Yes
libz => Yes
NTLM => Yes
NTLMWB => Yes
SPNEGO => No
SSL => Yes
SSPI => No
TLS-SRP => No
Protocols => dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, ldaps, pop3, pop3s, rtsp, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp
Host => x86_64-apple-darwin14.0
SSL Version => SecureTransport
ZLib Version => 1.2.5
```

But when I do phpinfo() and go to the page I do not see curl installed. 
I am adding phpinfo at the end of this question

So I tried several and many many things.

I tried removing homebrew curl by doing

brew rm curl
and then re-installing it with openssl option,

I also did phpize by downloading 5.6.5 version of php and compiling.

I even went ahead and installed macports program and that did not even help.

So my delimma is that curl is working form cli on my mac but not from webpage.

Here is my mac info

```
OSX Yosimite
10.10.2
```

Here is my phpinfo

[image]

Comment: Obviously Apache handler couldn't load curl extension in /usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extesion-curl.ini. Check back your phpinfo() output for Curl extension details. if it's not there. check out php's error log during apache restart.

Comment: thats my question why not? I couldnt see any php errors in tail -n 200 -f /var/log/apache/error_log

Comment: You have so many attempts an version here its likely you are getting confused about what is actually running and from where. Do you want to use the stock install, homebrew, or macports?

Comment: Be sure your php.ini doesn't suppress startup errors.  directives: display_startup_errors = On, log_errors = On, error_log = /usr/local/var/php_errors.   then use tail -f while you restart apache.

Comment: ok I will update my answer with the errors.